# Npm searching for package.json in the wrong directory

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, package.json

Hey I'm trying to install webpack right now.

I have everything setup, but when I try to run webpack inside my terminal, it searches for the `package.json` file in the wrong directory.

So my question is, can I change the path where npm tries to find my `package.json` file?

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/User/package.json
```

^error message I get after trying to run npm webpack in Terminal

```
{
  "name": "package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  }
}
```

^this is the package.json file from my project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You are in the wrong directory.**

Make sure you are in the right folder and then run `npm install webpack`.

In your terminal use `pwd` to print the current working directory and then `ls` to list all the files inside it. If there is no `package.json` you can't install anything.

Comment: Oh yea its set to home/User can I still change that somehow?

Comment: You just need to navigate with `cd` to your app directory.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but i am in the correct directory